# How to make a semicircular Hole in a rectangle side?

Tags: android, geometry, draw, shapes, android-shapedrawable

I need to make a rectangle which has a circle hole in middle something like this

[image]

Comment: use `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` - when implementing `Shape.draw()` method use `Canvas.drawPath()`

Comment: I do not know how to work with that can you show me complete code

Comment: what is in MyShape class ?

Comment: your shape you want to draw - it is done inside `draw()` method

Comment: I don't know how to draw my shape that's the question ;)

Comment: did you read `Path` class documentation? basically you need to use `Path` methods to form the `Path` and draw it using `Canvas.drawPath()` method

Comment: No I haven't ...

Comment: Check out the Porterduff mode. And see how to combine (or cut out) a mask from a bitmap. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode

Comment: what do you want it for? beside using Path and Canvas, I think an easy but not a very good way is to use an image view, make the image with photoshop or sth and use it in your project

Comment: @mohsen I was thinking that but I hoped there is better solution than that

Comment: there is but it's much harder :D

Comment: Take a look at the MaterialShapeDrawable in the MaterialComponents Library. Just apply the BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment on the bottom edge (or take it as example) to obtain your shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to obtain it.
You can use the Material Components Library and the [**`MaterialShapeDrawable`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) to create custom shape path (you need the version `1.1.0`)

For example you can do something like:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= findViewById(R.id.linear_rounded);
//Use the BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment to apply the bottom edge shape, or just create a custom class to obtain a similar shape
BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment = new BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment(
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin),
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.rounded_corner),
    getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.vertical_offset)
);
bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment.setFabDiameter(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.diameter));

ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
    .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,0)  
    .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,0)
    .setBottomEdge(bottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment)
    .build();
MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
ViewCompat.setBackground(linearLayout,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

Comment: that sounds perfect but i couldn't find MaterialShapeDrawable dependency can you add it too ?

Comment: @amirhesni You can find all [info here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md). Use the version 1.1.0-rc01